# Make multiple document roots?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, movabletype

I currently have my document root be the htdocs directory. Inside of that I have files relating to my domain name (index.html, style, everything) we will call this Site. Also in htdocs there is a directory called MT. This needs to stay here or else everything in Site gets messed up. So everything is great except that in order to see my website I have to do example.com/Site/index.html .... that is no good because I want to just do example.com. So I thought ok change the document root to htdocs/Site. That works but then I do not have access to changing my Movable Type interface. And I cannot move this directory from were it is.

I want to be able to say htdocs/Site is my document root and it will be example.com and have example.com/MT work as well without moving any directories around. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the filesystem, you should look into symbolic links:

`man ln`

```
 ln -s htdocs/MT htdocs/site/MT
```

This will create a symbolic link called MT in the directory htdocs/site/MT that refers to htdocs/MT ... **note** if you are using apache, you'll need to ensure it has the appropriate configuration to follow the symbolic links.

Comment: ok that works great. So I should change my document root to be htdocs/site so example.com will work now...just wonder if I want to host more than one site on here that really restricts things. Can I now say example.com document root is htdocs/site?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite enabled...

Create a .htaccess file in your Document Root, in it place the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(MT|Site) [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/Site/$1 [r=301,L]
```

This will redirect all requests to the /Site folder except requests for the /MT folder. It's automatic, practically invisible to the visitor and nice all around.

This will also allow people do get to your site from the base domain.

Comment: Actually, I did test it and it works smashingly. No need to change your document root or do anything else for that matter. The only drawback is that only the MT directory is safe from this rewrite. Though I am sure you can figure out how to exclude others as well by reading it.